# SharedPreferences -- Where do the initial values come from with a new app?

Tags: java, android

I've been looking into using preferences with an app that I have created.  For example:

One part of my app requires a CountDown timer.  The default for this count down timer should be 8:00 (8 minutes or 480000 ms).  However, I need the user to have the ability to change this to any value they want.

During my research, I have discovered the SharedPreferences ability built into Android but I'm a little confused how it works.

My thought was that the app will look for the shared preferences and if they aren't there use the defaults.  It doesn't seem to be working.  Once I install the new app (there currently isn't a Shared Preferences XML file, so I thought it would just load the defaults but I'm getting a null pointer error and the app crashes.

Here is my relevant code:

```
long
    msSavedMainClock = 0,
    msSavedShotClock = 0,
    msShotClockStart,
    msMainClockStart;

TextView 
    tvPeriodPrefix,
    tvPeriod;

// Create the SharedPreferences object
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);

// Create the Preference Editor object
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*******  more code here  *******/

    // Load the values/defaults from the SharedPreferences
    tvPeriodPrefix.setText( prefs.getString("Period_Prefix", getResources().getString(R.string.period)) );
    msMainClockStart = prefs.getLong( "Default_Main_Clock", 480000);    // 8 minute default
    msShotClockStart = prefs.getLong( "Default_Shot_Clock", 24000);     // 24 second default

    // Initialize other variables
    tvPeriod.setText( tvPeriodPrefix + "1" );

    /******* rest of my code here *******/
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Where exactly do you get a _NullPointerException_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences()` requires a valid Context, so the earliest you can run this code is in `onCreate()`:

```
// Create the SharedPreferences object
SharedPreferences prefs;

// Create the Preference Editor object
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
```

---

I may have answered a question like this before for you, so a good rule of thumb is: only try to set primitive variables outside of your methods. Variables like `int`, `long`, or even `String` are safe. But be wary of any data type that starts with a capital letter, (`String` is the one exception).

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I have followed your suggestion with regards to setting only primitive variables outside of my methods.  It doesn't look like this was causing the error though.  It seems as though it was another variable that I added but forgot to assign a value to.  That said, I don't think I have asked a similar question before that you have answered.  I have asked one other question regarding starting a new Activity for preferences but I created this new thread because I didn't think it would help to add to the previous question.